# I am handling the wordpress backend service, I want to get the JSONArray result

Tags: android

Java code look likes below;
Here I want to get the String to show to in the activity So, Anyone can help me to find the results String from the JSONArray

```
try {
JSONArray productJsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
int count = productJsonArray.length();
if (count != 0) {
for (int i = 0; i < productJsonArray.length(); i++) {
JSONObject productObject = productJsonArray
                .getJSONObject(i);
String pID = productObject.getString("ID");
String pTitle = productObject.getString("title");
String pSDesc = productObject.getString("content");
String pImgSrc = productObject
                                .getJSONArray("featured_image")
                                .optJSONObject(0).getString("source");
NewsModel model = new NewsModel();
        model.setName(pTitle);
        model.setDesc(pSDesc);
        model.setId(pID);
        model.setImageName(pImgSrc);
newsArrayList.add(model);
}
```

Here Is the JSON Rsult:

```
[2]
        0:  {
        ID: 216
        title: "New Farcry 4 release"
        status: "publish"
        modified_gmt: "2014-09-24T07:15:18"
        meta: {...}-
        featured_image: {
            ID: 217
            title: "Far-Cry-2-1422"
            status: "inherit"
            type: "attachment"
            author: {...}-
            parent: 216
            date: "2014-09-24T07:15:14"
            modified: "2014-09-24T07:15:14"
            format: "standard"
            source: "http://www.thusya.com/gamecom/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Far-Cry-2-1422.jpg"
    }-
    terms: [0]
}-
```

Here I have got the exception like below

```
09-25 19:06:24.308: W/System.err(12575):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
09-25 19:06:24.308: W/System.err(12575):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
09-25 19:06:24.308: W/System.err(12575):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
09-25 19:06:24.318: W/System.err(12575):    at com.tdzinfo.gamecom.News$GetNews.onPostExecute(News.java:101)
09-25 19:06:24.318: W/System.err(12575):    at com.tdzinfo.gamecom.News$GetNews.onPostExecute(News.java:1)
09-25 19:06:24.318: W/System.err(12575):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
09-25 19:06:24.318: W/System.err(12575):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
09-25 19:06:24.318: W/System.err(12575):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
09-25 19:06:24.318: W/System.err(12575):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-25 19:06:24.318: W/System.err(12575):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
09-25 19:06:24.318: W/System.err(12575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
09-25 19:06:24.318: W/System.err(12575):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-25 19:06:24.318: W/System.err(12575):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-25 19:06:24.318: W/System.err(12575):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
09-25 19:06:24.328: W/System.err(12575):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
09-25 19:06:24.328: W/System.err(12575):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So I want to know how can I handle this to get the Source name from this JSOn Result

Comment: I don't know where you got that JSON but that's not JSON. Check http://json.parser.online.fr/ to validate your json

Comment: Yeah this is not a well formed JSON Result. because it is getting from the WP backend. But It is also similar to JSON. Here, I can get the ID and the tittle, but could not be able to get the Source String...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`featured_image` is not an array but an object.

Change your line

`String pImgSrc = productObject.getJSONArray("featured_image").optJSONObject(0).getString("source");`

to

`String pImgSrc = productObject.getJSONObject("featured_image").getString("source");`